# Insertar datos en base de datos

Tags: php

estoy intentando insertar mis datos de un formulario y de una base de datos, es decir que de mi formulario agregue solo nomina y las fechas y al ejecutar en el INSERT me inserte lo relacionado con ese numero de nomina de la tabla empleado, vi que se hacia con un SELECT dentro del INSERT pero no me funciona, me podria orientar, que estoy haciendo mal. Les dejo mi codigo:

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO 
    roles_turno_emp 
    (NOMBRE,NOMINA,RUTA,F_INICIAL,F_FINAL) 
    VALUES 
    (SELECT nombre FROM empleado WHERE nomina = '$_POST[nomina]',
    '$_POST[nomina]',
    SELECT ruta FROM empleado WHERE nomina = '$_POST[nomina]'),
    '$_POST[fecha1]',
    '$_POST[fecha2]'");
```

Comment: Cuando decis no me funciona, tenes que especificar que error recibis.

Comment: Me ejecuta el insert, pero en mi tabla cuando reviso no inserta la informacion, no inserta nada.

Comment: Creo que tu consulta no está bien construida. Fijate que en los valores a asignar estás abriendo el parentesis en el primer valor pero lo cierras en el tercer valor. Puede ser eso? Por otro lado, asumo que nombre y ruta (el primer y tercer valor) son campos de texto. En ese caso, creo que debes entremocillarlos al igual que has hecho con os campos $_POST

Comment: Primero deberias probar tu query con variables manuales desde phpmyadmin una vez que sabes que funciona dicho query el problema seria por los parametros,,conexion..etc..

Comment: Puedes capturar el error desde PHP haciendo algo así: `if ( mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO 
    roles_turno_emp ---completa tu consulta la cual es sin duda muy mejorable---") ){echo "Todo ok"; } else {echo "Hubo un error". mysqli_error($con);}`

Comment: Como tal un error no me arroja, solo no me inserta nada, queria ver que parte del codigo estaba mal, o algun tip para poder realizar el insert de la informacion que necesito.

Answer (score 1):

Te propongo lo siguiente:
Hay cosas que debes considerar, como las validaciones, pero esto puede ayudarte.

```
//declaramos variables.
$nombreEmpleado = $ruta = $fecha1 = $fecha2 = "";
//bandera para permitir insertar si pasa todas las validaciones.
$valid = true;
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

if (empty($_POST["nomina"])) {
    $valid = false;
    echo "La nómina es requerida";
} else {
    $nomina = test_input($_POST["nomina"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["fecha1"])) {
    $valid = false;
    echo "La fecha 1 es requerida";
} else {
    $fecha1 = test_input($_POST["fecha1"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["fecha2"])) {
    $valid = false;
    echo "La fecha 2 es requerida";
} else {
    $fecha2 = test_input($_POST["nomina"]);
}

//Incluye tu conexión a la BD.
require 'tuConexion.php';
//Prepara la consulta para obtener el nombre y la ruta del empleado con la nómina que viene del post:
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT nombre, ruta FROM empleado WHERE nomina = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $nomina);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if ($stmt === false) {
    $valid = false;
    echo "Sucedió un error.";
}

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $nombreEmpleado = $row["nombre"];
        $ruta = $row["ruta"];
    }
} else {
    $valid = false;
    echo '<p>No existe empleado y ruta relacionado a esta nómina.</p><br>';
}

 //Si todo bien, que inserte a la BD (Usando sentencias preparadas). en bind_param defines el tipo de dato que esperas recibir.
 //Asumiendo que recibirás solo strings:
if ($valid) {
    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO roles_turno_emp(NOMBRE, NOMINA, RUTA, F_INICIAL, F_FINAL) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $nombreEmpleado, $nomina, $ruta, $fecha1, $fecha2);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Los datos han sido insertados correctamente :)";
    } else {
        echo "Ocurrió un error (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }
  }
 } 

 //Con la siguiente función validamos plecas, espacios, caracteres especiales:
  function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
 }
```

Comment: tu `SELECT` es inseguro por que pasas el valor de la variable lo pasas directo

Comment: Tienes razón, agregué una función para poder escapar caracteres innecesarios, valores vacíos, etc. Acá depende de lo que Xavi va a pasar, si es un entero una cadena de caracteres. Esperemos que él valide del lado del cliente esas entradas.

Comment: de hecho tener esto en tu consulat sigue siendo inseguro `$nomina` aqui lo que debes implementar es consultas preparadas, por otro lado solo validar del lado del cliente sigue siendo inseguro

Comment: ¿Serías tan amable de editar esta parte para poder apreciar cómo se valida de la manera más adecuada, por favor?

Answer (score 1):

Para que tu consulta funcione tal y cual la has escrito debes corregir el cierre de paréntesis para los campos `NOMBRE` y `RUTA`

```
INSERT INTO 
    roles_turno_emp(NOMBRE,NOMINA,RUTA,F_INICIAL,F_FINAL) 
VALUES 
    (SELECT nombre FROM empleado WHERE nomina = '$nomina'), <-------- cierre aquí
    '$nomina',
    (SELECT ruta FROM empleado WHERE nomina = '$nomina'), <-------- cierre aquí
    '$fecha1',
    '$fecha2'
```

1- Adicional a este es MUY importante que revises la seguridad de las variables que estás pasando a tus consultas, debes sanitizarlas para evitar la inyección de código malicioso a tus consultas que incluso podrías borrar toda tu base de datos, preocúpate!
http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php

2- Debes optimizar tu código porque estás haciendo dos consultas para obtener dos campos y es una aberración a la optimización :) y es más, antes de modificar tu código para optimizar esas dos consultas te recomendaría que este insert lo convirtieras a un procedimiento almacenado y hagas las correcciones ahí.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html